# one to many relationship vs. multiple records in a single table

Tags: database, database-design, payment-gateway, entity-relationship

I'm designing a payment system. Which of the following two designs is more practical, generally implemented and considered a good practice?

### **Design 1**

Consider two entities — `order` and `credit_card_details`.

A credit card might be used for payment of several orders. So we have a 1:M relationship between `credit_card_details` and `order`. Keep in mind that each record in `credit_card_details` is unique with the attributes like card_holder_name, cvv, expiry_date, etc. These are filled in a form while making the payment. This design requires that whenever a payment is made, I would need to lookup the `credit_card_details` table to check whether a new/old credit card is being used. If the credit card is —

- Old: The corresponding FK is added to the `order` table.
- New: A new record is added in `credit_card_details` and then the corresponding FK is added to the `order` table

### Design 2

This is relatively simpler. I use a single `order` table where all the attributes of `credit_card_details` from the previous design are merged to the former table. Whenever an order is placed, I need not check for the existence of the entered credit card details and I simply insert them in `order` table. However, it comes with the cost of possible duplicate credit card details.

Comment: You may wish to think about your domain object model a little more.  An `Order` very typically has a one-to-many relationship with `LineItems` but a one-to-one relationship with a `Payment` (which can be a credit card).  It is not logical, for example, to process a credit authorization for more than one `Order` instance.  A one-to-many cardinality between `credit_card_details` and `order` doesn't feel right.

Comment: The system does not perform more than one order in a single instance. Consider that you placed an order today with one of your credit cards and you placed another one tomorrow using the same one.

Comment: Just a stylistic note: entities are typically classes in the in-memory object domain.  When using ORM tools, entities correspond to tables in a relational database.  Naming conventions are different.  You would not name an entity `credit_card_details` because, for example, this is not concordant with Java naming conventions (you -could- name the corresponding table that way).  Instead, the entity would be named like `CreditCardDetails`.

Comment: I'm using MySQL, which automatically converts all upper case characters to lower case, hence CamelCase doesn't help much.

Comment: MySQL is the relational database which has tables, not entities.  Entity is usually taken to mean an object within the domain object model of an object-oriented language like Java.

Answer (score 1):

Personally option one makes sense, option 2 does not give you 3NF, and the data is denormalized and hence you may have duplicated data. What if the customer returns the order and you want to make a reverse payment and the card has expired? These are just some common curveballs I am throwing up. It all depends on the given scenarios.

Also how imagine that you wanted a history of all the credit cards associated to a user and against the orders???, what would be a logical way to store these in the database? Surely a separate table right?

So a given user may have 0 to many cards.
A card can be associated to 1 or many orders
And an order is always associated to one card.

Consider possible searching options as well, and look up speed, better to have a unique foreign key in the order table.

A third option might be to have an Order table, Card table and OrderCard table although personally again it depends on your domain, although I think option three may be overkill?

Hope this helps in your design

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I understand that the first design is more normalized. What I want to know is whether it is a good practice to lookup the `credit_card_details` when online transactions are concerned? Is it a traditional method?

Comment: Again it depends... You may or may not want to look up credit card details.  Think of the various mechanisms of online payments, normally users can add update delete card details? ie amazon. So maybe you may want to take that into consideration. Also some systems may use a payment gateway for online transaction processing etc. Which may entirely may a seperate system or service etc etc

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I've upvoted your answer. If I don't get a more satisfactory answer, I'll accept yours.